# I want to make a book that tilts randomly

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I want to create a book that tilts randomly with geometry nodes as shown in the image!
It is not an animation, but a still image
[image]

I created a node like this.
[image]

But with my knowledge I could only create this...
[image]

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean an animation like falling dominoes?

Comment: ...or just a still image?

Comment: you can tilt and align a single book to the wall (or another book) and the floor with GN. For a row of books you need to do this from left to right for each book individually. I think you need a Repeat Zone (Blender 4) or Simulation Nodes for this if you want to create the row of books with a GN modifier.

Comment: @lemon &Chris Thanks for commenting!
Sorry, this is intended to be a still image

Comment: @Chris Added to the question text

Comment: @Blunder I have no knowledge of repeating nodes or simulation nodes as I have never used them. Are there any good tutorial videos on this question?

Comment: @InamuraJIN I haven't done much with repeating nodes and simulation nodes either. But I think it's doable with them. I've figured out how to loop over the instances. But at the moment the pivot point for rotation/tilt doesn't work as it should when I put everything together. My first idea to tilt the book also was too complicated, you can do it much simpler. I can show you what I got so far later.

Comment: Can you confirm that you really want randomly tilted books? I suspect that you want instead randomly positioned books, the tilt of which results from the imprecise positioning. Or to put it differently: If you place books with differently sized gaps in between on your shelve and push them over, do they arrange as you want? Randomly tilted books in regular distance seem to be what you describe and what is the approach in what you have shown, but they are not natural, they look like separatly glued to the back of the shelve.

Comment: Apart from that you are asking about geometry nodes to do this and stress that it is a still image, not a simulatio nor animation. However, rigid body simulation would be the path I would try, evene if the final goal is a still image. Just simulare, wait uintil the books stop moving and take the picture. Is that out of the question for you?

Comment: @Yunnosch I wanted to randomize the type, thickness, height, and number of books. Furthermore, I wanted to change them into products such as potato chips. So I wanted to reproduce it in GeoNode, but the more I thought about it, the more difficult it proved to be. Surely a rigid body would be easier